invalid token error while decrypting using cryptography.fernet library
i am using django to build an ecommerce website and in my views.py i have a function that encrypts the password and enters it into database and another function that tries to decrypt the password in database and tries to match it with entered password.
from django.shortcuts import render
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
from django.conf import settings
import os
from .models import Userdetails
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from datetime import date
from django.db import connection
def read_pw_and_encrypt(password):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'Bidbay1', 'static', 'Bidbay1', 'sample.txt')
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            file_content = file.read()
            f=Fernet(file_content)
            y=f.encrypt(password.encode())            
            
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise HttpResponse("File does not exist")

    return y

def fetch_pw_and_decrypt(username):
      try:
        # Load the encryption key from the file
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Bidbay1', 'static', 'Bidbay1', 'sample.txt')
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            key = file.read().strip()  # Ensure the key is correctly read

        # Ensure the key is the correct length for Fernet (32 bytes)
        if len(key) != 44:
            raise ValueError("Invalid key length. Ensure the key is 32 bytes URL-safe base64-encoded string.")

        f = Fernet(key)

        # Fetch the encrypted password from the database
        password_obj = Userdetails.objects.get(user_name=username)
        encrypted_password = password_obj.user_pwd  # Ensure the password is in bytes
        print(f"Encrypted password: {encrypted_password}")

        # Decrypt the password
        decrypted_password = f.decrypt(encrypted_password).decode()
        print(f"Decrypted password: {decrypted_password}")

        return decrypted_password

      except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {e}")
        raise e

when i try to decrypt the db password the following error pops up
InvalidToken
No exception message supplied
Exception Location: C:\Users\ASUS\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py, line 118, in _get_unverified_token_data
i tried generating a new key but didnt work, tried making a new sample file and storing there but still didnt work

The code works for me (but tested without DB). So it is probably due to the data: inconsistent keys, corrupted data (e.g. when saving to/loading from the DB), etc. Is the ciphertext identical immediately after encryption and immediately before decryption? Log and compare the values. Check the key in the same way. Post test data: key, plaintext, ciphertext.
